# In gradle, how can a test configuration declare a dependency upon another project's test configuration?

Tags: testing, gradle, dependencies, classpath

In gradle 5.6.2, I have a project with sub-projects. The tests in the sub-projects share a lot of code, so I'd like sub-projects tests to depend upon parent projects tests. But references in tests do not resolve, even though references in the main projects do. The Gradle docs say to use a "map notation" dependency declaration, and this dependencies block does not generate errors:

```
dependencies {
    api project(":henchbot-api")
    testImplementation project(path: ':henchbot-api', configuration: 'testRuntime')
}
```

... but the tests won't compile. If I change `testRunTime` to `testRuntimeClasspath` then gradle fails to resolve that project dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will also need to declare the test artefact - see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies

in the project `henchbot-api`

```
configurations {
    testLib
}

task testLibJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveBaseName = archivesBaseName + '-testLib'
    from sourceSets.test.output
}

artifacts {
    testLib testLibJar
}
```

in the other one - the dependency is

```
testImplementation project(path: ':henchbot-api', configuration: 'testLib')
```

Comment: Thanks!
This works, I added the three blocks to my subprojects block. Is there a reason a new configuration needs to be created? Are there issues defining artifacts for the built-in test configurations?

Comment: And isn't this a gradle bug, where there is no exception thrown when the project dependency declaration cannot read the required, but non-existing, artifact for the "testRuntime" configuration?